# Audio drivers for HP AY15 503TX laptop

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio

I recently started using Ubuntu 17.04 in my HP-AY15 -503TX notebook.

Before this I was using Windows 10 and there were Realtek HD audio drivers for audio and sound was so clear, but in Ubuntu sound is not so audible and clear.

I checked all my settings and also tried different headphones but sound quality is still poor.

I used rhythmbox, VLC and smplayer but results are same.
can I install Realtek HD audio drivers in Ubuntu? Or are there any other options for good quality audio??